# Waking up rMBP via Keyboard Attached to TB Display Doesn't Work

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, thunderbolt-display

rMBP has 10.8.2 installed. Both TB display and rMBP are brand new as of last a few days ago.

I've got a USB mouse and keyboard (wired) plugged into the TB display. The TB display is hooked up to the mac via the TB port. After I go to the apple logo and click Sleep, I cannot wake the mac up by hitting keys on the external keyboard or clicking the external mouse. In order to get it to wake up, I have to either open the screen on the laptop or press a key on the laptop's built in keyboard.

Has anyone else experienced this problem? I've also had problems with the Mac not waking up from deep sleep (hibernatemode 3). Is 10.8.2 simply trash?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this problem? I'm running into a similar problem with El Capitan (10.11.3).

Answer (score 1):

Yep, I'm seeing the same thing. After deep sleep, my MBPR connected to my TB display won't wake up and starts spinning the CPU. I've only experienced this after I've shut my MBPR. The work around - I shutdown the MBPR now after I use it.

Comment: Did you ever find a different solution for this problem?